# Aptana will not let me Run my python modules. Why?

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, aptana, pydev

Why is the Python Run option not available?

[image: Where is the "Python Run" option?]

I'm running Aptana 3 on Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: do you have a python file opened?

Comment: Woops! I added a new screenshot. It's still not working!

Comment: is it a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: Anyway, options listed in the menu are for testing. Open the shell, go to your app directory and run python your_app.py

Comment: I'm trying to use Aptana to develop my program and need that option to test it.

Comment: then, maybe changing the question will be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Python run should be available if you have a python file opened in the builtin python editor of Aptana.